# How to extract artifact name from download-artifact actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to store the artifact name alone in a variable. So tried something like the following to see if I can extract the artifact name. But below changes don't really give any results. Am I missing something ?

```
  - name: Download Artifact for Deployment
    id: jdm
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: jdmessenger
  - name: Check Download Results
    run: echo ${{ steps.jdm.outputs.all }}
```